# Gather Serial Numbers for computer on network using an ip range /Node wmic

Tags: for-loop, ip-address, wmic

Im trying to get serial numbers from computers on a network. Currently I have trying using the following For loop to run through an IP range of 192.168.0..... and then using wmic bios get serialnumber get the serialnumber a system assigned to that IP address.

I get the error invalid node syntax.  Is there something wrong with this or is there an easier way to do this.

```
(FOR /L %s IN (1,1,254) DO wmic /node 192.168.0.%s wmic bios get serialnumber) >> c:\Users\loxley\Desktop\test.txt
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: tried to remove the second `wmic`?

Answer (score 0):

/node should have a colon after it????? @ means the name/ip(s) are in a text file.

```
/node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt"

/node:127.0.0.1
```